# UnsatisfiedLinkError while running OpenCV Mixed Processing Tutorial

Tags: android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I compiled Tutorial 2 - Mixed Processing demo from OpenCV samples. I made following changes to it so that it works without the OpenCV Package Manager.

Added a static section to initialize OpenCV:

```
static {
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        // Handle initialization error
        Log.i(TAG, "OpenCVLoader Failed");
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "OpenCVLoader Succeeded");
        System.loadLibrary("mixed_process");
    }
}
```

Removed mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
}
```

I get this error when I run the app:

**Error:**

```
08-19 13:21:35.455: E/AndroidRuntime(2388): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(int, int, int) (tried Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat and Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat__III)
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out myself, problem was that I wasn't loading the libopencv_java3.so in my application. It is working fine after I fixed it.

```
static {
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        // Handle initialization error
        Log.i(TAG, "OpenCVLoader Failed");
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "OpenCVLoader Succeeded");
        System.loadLibrary("CameraVision");
        System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3");
    }
}
```